# Select not clickable on the entire block

Tags: css, react-native, native-base

So I recently upgreade native-base and I am using Select on my react native app, however, the Select is not triggered until you click on the dropdown arrow only, if you click anywhere else, it will not triggered the dropdown.   any thoughts?  Here is my code.

```
let testTypeOptions = [
  { value: 6, label: 'Maternity Test' },
  { value: 18, label: 'Paternity Test' },
];

<Container style={cocStyle.container}>
  <View style={cocStyle.formContainer}>
  <Select
    selectedValue={examDetail?.testType}
    onValueChange={value => handleChange('testType', value)}>
    {testTypeOptions.map((test, index) => (
      <Select.Item key={index} {...test} />
    ))}
  </Select>
  </View>
</Container>

const cocStyle = StyleSheet.create({
  container: { paddingTop: 10, width: '60%', alignSelf: 'center' },
  formContainer: {
    ...formStyles.formWrapper,
    width: '100%',
    flexWrap: 'wrap',
    flexDirection: 'row',
  },
});
```

[image]

Comment: Could you please share the value of `testTypeOptions` and the parent component wrapped over the `<Select>...</Select>` component?

Comment: @FutureJJ done, I update it in the original question

Comment: I am unable to reproduce this issue on any of these platforms: Web, iOS, Android; I am able to open the menu on touching the entire area(not just the drop-down). I used the exact snippet provided in the question just that I removed `...formStyles.formWrapper,` from the style because I do not know its value. Maybe there is some issue with the `formStyles.formWrapper` style?